# Why is Google Reader not showing site favicons?

Tags: google-reader

In my Linux partition, Google Reader is not showing the site favicons, why is this so ? Is this a Google Reader or a Google Chrome bug ?

I'm using Google Chrome 7.0.517.5 dev

Here's a screenshot

[image: favicon]

And yes, I have enabled Show favicons in Reader settings

[image: settings]

Comment: Wow! I learnt something new here, I didn't even know you *could* show favicons. Sorry that's no help for your question though...

Comment: @Benjol No worries :) @Dominik & @rassie helped me out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's broken: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=54926

According to comments, it will be fixed in the next iteration of developer releases.

Comment: Thanks, starred the bug. Will update when the bug gets fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's a Google Chrome bug. My 7.0.517.5 dev doesn't show them, Epiphany does.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firefox+Greasemonkey there are some scripts to get the favicons. For Chrome the Greasemonkey equivalent is Greasemetal. May be someone who has installed it can provide link for the chrome browser utility.